# Unwanted transparency in OpenGL

Tags: cocoa, opengl

I am making a textured cube with the following code, but the closer the vertices get to the viewer, the more transparent they get. In addition, the texture seems to be completely invisible.

```
float rot = 0.01;

@implementation ECGameView

- (void)prepareOpenGL {
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE_ARB);

    GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat mat_shininess[] = { 50.0 };
    GLfloat lightPosition[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
    GLfloat white_light[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat lmodel_ambient[] = { 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0 };

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, white_light);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, white_light);
    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, lmodel_ambient);

    NSImage * texImg = [NSImage imageNamed:@"texture.png"];
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    NSBitmapImageRep * bitmap = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[texImg TIFFRepresentation]];
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, [texImg size].width, [texImg size].height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, [bitmap bitmapData]) ;
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

    updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.05 target:self selector:@selector(update:) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];
}

- (void) update:(NSTimer*)timer; {
    [self setNeedsDisplay:TRUE];
}

- (void)reshape {
    NSSize size = self.bounds.size;
    glViewport(0,0, size.width, size.height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, size.width/size.height, 0.1, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -10.0);
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glRotatef(rot, 1, 0, 1);
    rot = (rot + .01);

    static GLfloat vertices[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0};

    static GLfloat normals[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0};

    static const GLfloat texCoords[] = {
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 0.0
    };

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 24);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glFlush();
}
```

All of the drawing is done in `ECGameView`, which is a subclass of NSOpenGLView, with a `Gluint` variable in the header. Does anybody have any ideas?

By the way, I know it is a lot of code, but I honestly don't know what is wrong, and all of these things seem to apply.

EDIT: I just removed the coloring in my code, and it shows an orange cube. I think that means the texture is sort of working (texture below, from http://www.nullterminator.net/gltexture.html).

[image: The texture I am using for this test]

EDIT 2: *PLEASE* help me figure this out. The texturing issue has been solved, but they issue I was asking about has *not*. I am getting a strange hole in one side of the cube. Code has been updated

[image: Strange hole]

EDIT 3: I figured out *why* it is doing thing, but I do not know how to fix it. It is drawing the texture on the wrong side of the plane (the back side of the cube). How can I make it draw on the correct side?

Comment: Are you sure they get transparent? Have you tried changing the background see if they actually get transparent or maybe darker? If they get darker, it would be because of your lighting.

Comment: And what do you mean the texture is invisible? Do you mean you see the cube only in color and not with texture? Or the whole object when textured is somehow invisible?

Comment: Have you set the texture environment mode?

Comment: I _think_ the texture just isn't showing up, but I have done error checking and it is loaded properly. It is very confusing.

Comment: I just checked the coloring and I can actually see _through_ the first half of the cube. I can see the two sides and the bottom connecting.

Comment: @BrettHale I just did (in the code now). Only shows an orange cube, and only if I remove coloring from my code.

Comment: @Justin: maybe just stick with `GL_REPLACE` until you get the texturing sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see texturing enabled anywhere. `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`

edit: I also think you will need 24 (s, t) texture coordinate pairs.

finally: It looks like you haven't enabled backface culling: `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);`
You should also look at `glPolygonMode`, if the vertex ordering (winding) of the faces aren't CCW (counter-clockwise) by default.

Comment: How do I put those in? I have no idea what you mean by "24 (s, t) texture coordinate pairs"

Comment: @Justin: You've only provided texture coordinates for the first GL_QUAD. You want to do that another 5 times. the GL is probably reading garbage past the end of the texCoords array.

Comment: That worked. Unfortunately, that still leaves me with that strange transparency problem. I am going to post a picture of it in a few minutes.

Comment: I still have a square hole in one of the 6 sides. It makes almost half of the side transparent